# Crystal Reports with RIA Services

Tags: wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, crystal-reports-2010

I am new with Silverlight and I can get the data from my database into a grid using Domain Service in my Silverlight app.

But I want to take the data that has been 'filled' by the Domain Service in to a Crystal Report Viewer in a ASP.NET Web Page as a Pop-up.

I have done the same for MS Reporting Services after following an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97452/Integrate-Reporting-Services-with-Silverlight-and?msg=4321239#xx4321239xx).

But how can I accomplish the same for SAP's Crystal Reports? Suggestions required urgently please

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to use WCF Ria Services EntityQuery serialization capability to dynamically create a query client-side than send the result of the query to your report. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yeah, that'll do also. Any examples please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as simple as one may think, and I don't have something ready, however:

1. Override the query method
2. put a check on a custom cookie that will prevent the execution of the query will saving in the ASP session the Expression of the Query property.
3. Write a web page that contains the Crystal Report Viewer: when invoked, that page will look for the Expression saved int point 2 and will execute it with your IQueryable in order to get the result to supply to Crystal Report. (You may want to convert this IEnumerable to a datatable in a dataset)
4. Client side, simply call the Context.Load of your type and set the same cookie as the point 2, expect nothing back, then open the aspx page with the viewer.

As you can see it's not easy, but... feasible.